# Django push to Heroku: "Unknown command: 'compress'"?

Tags: django, bash, heroku, django-compressor, wagtail

I'm trying to deploy a fresh Django/Wagtail app to Heroku, but having trouble.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://wagtail.io/blog/deploying-wagtail-heroku/), which works until the last section "Serving static assets on Heroku".  When I push the app to Heroku with `git push heroku master`, however, it fails with this error:

```
...
remote:        182 static files copied to '/app/static', 182 post-processed.
remote: 
remote: -----> Running run_compress
remote: -----> Compressing static files
remote:        Unknown command: 'compress'
remote:        Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to myapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
$
```

Presumably Heroku is having trouble with Django Compressor, although the tutorial does not specify its installation, so I'm not sure.  The tutorial specifies instead the installation of something called [Heroku Django Cookbook](https://github.com/nigma/heroku-django-cookbook), which specifies a `run_compress` in a `bash` file which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eo pipefail

indent() {
    RE="s/^/       /"
    [ $(uname) == "Darwin" ] && sed -l "$RE" || sed -u "$RE"
}

MANAGE_FILE=$(find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name 'manage.py' | head -1)
MANAGE_FILE=${MANAGE_FILE:2}

echo "-----> Compressing static files"
python $MANAGE_FILE compress 2>&1 | indent

echo
```

So it seems `manage.py compress` isn't working.  Or else it might be something with Whitenoise, since that's the section of tutorial which is failing.  Seems to be installed right, though.  Here are the relevant lines from my `settings.py`:

```
...
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
    'compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter',
]
COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD = 'content'
...
```

finally, here is my `requirements.txt`

```
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
dj-database-url==0.4.1
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.9.6
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-compressor==2.0
django-modelcluster==1.1
django-taggit==0.18.3
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
django-treebeard==4.0.1
djangorestframework==3.3.3
gunicorn==19.6.0
html5lib==0.9999999
Pillow==3.2.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2016.4
rcssmin==1.0.6
requests==2.10.0
rjsmin==1.0.12
six==1.10.0
static3==0.7.0
Unidecode==0.4.19
wagtail==1.4.5
whitenoise==3.2
Willow==0.3.1
```

Any ideas?  All leads welcome.  Thank you!

Comment: ust this https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/content/heroku/ .

Comment: or you can follow step by step video for deploying django project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Mx8JLtNmvw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you didn't add `compressor` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Also worth mentioning that Wagtail no [longer depends on `django_compressor`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.2/releases/1.4.html#removal-of-django-compressor) since version 1.4, so if you don't need `django_compressor`'s functionality, you can just remove it from your project.

Comment: Thanks, seems pretty obvious in retrospect.  I just commented out that section from Heroku Django Cookbook.

Comment: Awesome, works now.  Can you comment on what changed in Wagtail to lose that requirement?

Comment: @niteshade: the Wagtail admin ships with pre-compressed stylesheets rather than compressing them on the fly.